# Build DB connection string from environment variables

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm using the Play Framework (Java) and am not able to figure out how to use environment variables in my configuration file for building the database connection string. While I'm able to use environment variables like this (for user name and password):

```
default.username = ${?FU_MAIN_DB_USERNAME}
default.password = ${?FU_MAIN_DB_PASSWORD}
```

I'm not able to make it work in the `url` string. Perhaps this is a simple case of string processing in Scala that I'm missing, but since I'm working in Java, I could use some help.

So far, I have tried the `url` string in the following formats and failed:

Tried to add a $ to variable name to perform interpolation:

default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://$${?FU_MAIN_DB_HOST}:$${?FU_MAIN_DB_PORT}/$${?FU_MAIN_DB_NAME}";

But this doesn't substitute. Rather, it picks the string as such.

```
default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://${?FU_MAIN_DB_HOST}:${?FU_MAIN_DB_PORT}/${?FU_MAIN_DB_NAME}";
```

This too inserts the '$' and all verbatim. Then I thought maybe something like PHP-style will work

```
default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://${${?FU_MAIN_DB_HOST}}:${${?FU_MAIN_DB_PORT}}/${${?FU_MAIN_DB_NAME}}";
```

But no.

I also tried doing stuff like `"jdbc:postgresql://".concat(${?FU_MAIN_DB_HOST}) ...` but this also inserts '.concat' verbatim.

Finally, I tried concatenation using the '+' operator, but I'm told (by my IDE) that symbols like +: etc. are not allowed in the `application.conf` file.

How then, in God's name, am I supposed to do that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes turn off interpolation. But you need to do that for the `:` and the `//`.

Try

```
default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://"${?FU_MAIN_DB_HOST}":"${?FU_MAIN_DB_PORT}/${?FU_MAIN_DB_NAME}
```

Maybe you are better off to set the whole thing in one big environment variable instead.

Comment: Very nice suggestion, but I think it's better to keep things modular. On the syntax, though, it's pretty weird that the full string was produced without any operator or anything. A mystery for another day, perhaps! :-)

Comment: Well, the quotes are terrible. Without the special characters, it would look pretty okay: `foo = ${?BASE_DIR}/${app.prefix}/tmp/${http.hostname}`